# update in firebase is not working(with React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is my firebase database, i am trying to update or retrieving Username and this is my code and but nothing works. please guide me. i am pretty new to it. thanks.

```
    var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref('KPA8kdldBb-okGSYepl').once("child_added").key;


    firebase.database().ref('KPA8kdldBb-okGSYepl').orderByChild( 'Password').equalTo('ertret').once("child_added", (snapshot) => {

        var datas1 = [];
        snapshot.forEach((data1) =>
        {

            datas1.push( {

                username: data1.val().Username,

            });

        });

        this.setState ({
            datas1: datas1,
        });

    });

    console.log(this.state.datas1);

}
```

My code is not working, can somebody guide me, how to proceed with this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors, if so what are they in your browser console?

Comment: no man.. no error ... when i am doing  console.log(this.state.datas1);  .....  it is showing empty array.